# Define multiplication on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, convolution, banach-algebras

I want to define multiplication on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, of course, convolution is an allowed multiplication which makes $(L^1(\mathbb{R}),*)$ is a Banach algebra, I want to know if there are other products that multiplication $\bullet$ that $(L^1(\mathbb{R}),\bullet)$ is a Banach algebra.

Comment: Since translation is an automorphism of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, convolution conjugated by a translation operator gives another multiplication. You can also conjugate by any other automorphism of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Also, you can consider the Haar measure $\mu$ of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ as a multiplicative group. $\mu$ has density $1/|x|$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, so you can multiply by $|x|$, sending $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ to $L^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}, \mu)$, and then apply the convolution product on the latter algebra. That gives another Banach algebra structure.

Comment: Perhaps more generally, $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to the $L^1$ space of any separable atomless $\sigma$-finite measure space, which would include most non-discrete locally compact groups equipped with their Haar measures that arise in practice. So basically you can equip $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with a Banach algebra structure that’s isomorphic to the convolution algebra of any such group.